# Apply condition to Excel Repeating Row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am printing a table in Excel and therefore will need its column to repeat on every page when printing. The problem is that the repeating row also appears to the last page where it doesn't need to be.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice that in the third and last page, the repeating column is shown. What I want to do is for it not to repeat anymore if there are not table element in the page. Can it be done? I'm using Excel 2016 if that helps.

Note: The rows of the table may vary height in the actual usage of this worksheet. It is not also not always 65 rows, sometimes it goes lower or higher.

I'm using this wizard to set the repeating rows.[image]

Comment: Means You want it to be printed Except the Last page?

Comment: I don't think through buit-in excel commands it's possible to control the print Row on every page except the last one. **But I can suggest you VBA code will help you to stop the ROW to be printed on last Page.**

Comment: @RajeshS Not necessary. I want it not to be printed if the table is not found on the last page. But if there ut at least one row on the last page, then the column should still be printed on the last page.